# Link implementation between two modules

Tags: android, gradle

I'm currently designing an app. I'have separate my code into two co-dependend  module.

The first one include all my mother class and include some extern library. The second one include the first one to use its classes. Is there a way to also merge the implementation of extern Library. To avoid to reclare it in the second module gradle file ?

Thank you 
Guillaume

Comment: any specific reason to split your code base into two ?

Comment: its for reuse. The first module contain all my Rx,Retrofit architecture that can be used on other, futur, project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly you have
`ModuleB` -> Depends on `LibraryX`
`ModuleA` -> Depends on `LibraryX` & `ModuleB`

You don't want to have to add LibraryX into the gradle file for `ModuleA`? If that is the case declare the dependency for `LibraryX` as `api` instead of `implementation` in `ModuleB`'s gradle file

For more info check out [this](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)